# useEffect fetches data after using the data | ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am creating a random quote generator. Everything works fine. But the quote doesn't appear at the page reload. I have to click new quote button to get a new quote. It should also display a quote when the DOM is loaded.

My Code:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
     const quotesURL ='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json';

const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
const [randomQuote, setRandomQuote] = useState('');

const fetchQuotes = useCallback(() => {
    fetch(quotesURL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setQuotes(data.quotes))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));

    // console.log(quotes);
}, [quotesURL]);

// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
const handleNewQuote = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    setRandomQuote(quotes[randomIndex]);
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuotes();
}, []);

return (
    <div>
        <div id='quote-box'>
            <div id='text'>{randomQuote.quote}</div>
            <div id='author'>{randomQuote.author}</div>
            <button id='new-quote' onClick={handleNewQuote}>
                New Quote
            </button>
            <a href='https://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet' id='tweet-quote'>
                Tweet Quote
            </a>
        </div>
        {quotes?.map((quote, index) => (
            <div key={index}>{JSON.stringify(quote)}</div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

What I want is to display a quote at the reload of the page. It currently works only when the button is clicked!

The problem according to my understanding is that the useEffect calls `fetchQuotes()` after `handleNewQuote()`, so there is no quote to load

Comment: Actually you are wrong, `handleNewQuote` will only be called when clicking your "New Quote" button. `fetchQuotes` will be called right after the component has been mounted, and thus not making possible to be called if you have not clicked the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the following in your component:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!randomQuote) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
        setRandomQuote(quotes[randomIndex]);
    }
}, [quotes]);
```

This runs when the quotes have been loaded and but random quote is still null.

Or even better, call `setRandomQuote()` at the time you fetch quotes.

```js
const fetchQuotes = useCallback(() => {
    fetch(quotesURL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
           const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.quotes.length);
           setRandomQuote(data.quotes[randomIndex]);
           setQuotes(data.quotes)
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
}, [quotesURL]);
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/random-quote-sxrdrt?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to do it, but I think the best one would be to set random quote when the data is loaded. It can be done after fetch or in useEffect

So I'd do following

```
const handleNewQuote = useCallback(() => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    setRandomQuote(quotes[randomIndex]);
}, [quotes, setRandomQuote])

// useCallback so it can be passed to useEffect safely without infinite loop (memoize function when component rerenders)



useEffect(() => {
  handleNewQuote()
}, [quotes, handleNewQuote])
```